# how to eliminate duplicate from large amount of data while crawling

Tags: java, set, web-crawler

I am crawling large amount of data from shopping websites. for example consider i am crawling 200 pages of data and each page has 30 product details. i am crawling name, price, imageURL and productURL. productURL shud not be repeating.. how can i check weather the product URL is repeating or not while crawling and avoid the non repeating value to the database . i will give the sample code which i tried below..

```
public void process(ArrayList<Item> results) {
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

    System.out.println("*****************OUTPUT****************");
    StringBuilder dataBuilder;

    System.out.println("TOTAL ITEMS " + results.size());

    for (Item item : results) {
        item.setSrc(xmlData.getSrc());

        if (!item.getName().trim().equals("")
                && !item.getPrice().trim().equals("")
                && !item.getUrl().trim().equals("")) {

            if (s.add(item.getUrl())) {
                dao.insertToDB(item, xmlData.getOutput_DB());
            } else {
                system.out.println("url is repeating");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("first loop failedddd");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using set here but still after inserting finished i could get some duplicate url .. i could not understand the problem. please help me with this.

Comment: Set will only add unique String and it is case sensitive. Are you sure you are getting duplicate URLs?

Comment: yes i am getting suplicate. because i wrote another code to check the duplicate data from database and i am getting some.  and actually i got the solution now.. the Set object was declared locally and each time when i was calling this process() function a new object is creating. now i declared it as global. and set object is creating just once.  thanks for your support any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!item.getName().trim().equals("")
    && !item.getPrice().trim().equals("")
        && !item.getUrl().trim().equals(""))
{
    if (s.contains(item.getUrl())) {
        system.out.println("url is repeating");
    }
    else {
        dao.insertToDB(item, xmlData.getOutput_DB());
        s.add(item.getUrl());
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("first loop failedddd");
}
```

Comment: s.add() will only add into the set if and only if the object is not equals. It returns false if it fails to add (ie. object equals) and true otherwise.

Comment: yes i am getting suplicate. because i wrote another code to check the duplicate data from database and i am getting some.  and actually i got the solution now.. the Set object was declared locally and each time when i was calling this process() function a new object is creating. now i declared it as global. and set object is creating just once.  But this looks like a better code to check.. i will use s.contains now to check.. thank you.

Comment: your welcome Sarath. enjoy coding and stackoverflow.